# Visual Studio Source code checked out by someone else

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 and a few of my files says Checked out by someone else or in another place. I go to View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer and I can see which files are pending change.

How do I get those changes if that person has not yet checked in the code?

Comment: What VCS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using TFS and the code is not checked in, then you can't access it.  If the other person wants to share the changes with you without checking them in, the other person can ["shelve" the changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which lets you access them.

Answer (score 1):

Because the source code has not been published to the server yet, there's no way to fetch the changes made by that person. If you need those changes, you should talk to that person I guess.